# Why Springboot @requestbody parameter always receives empty?

Tags: java, spring-boot, post

all. I currently met an unexpected situation. I completed my API, and I hope to have a test by Postman; however, I do not know why I always get an empty bracket `{}`. How can I fix it?

```
@PostMapping(value="/register")
public Status registerSingleConnection(@RequestBody JSONObject param){
    System.out.printlin(param); // para always be {}
    ....
}
```

This is what I tried in `generated-requests.http`:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8082/register
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "id": "1",
    "val": "999"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions you can follow.

**1. Use string as request body and convert to json**

```
    @PostMapping(value="/register")
    public Map<String, Object> registerSingleConnection(@RequestBody String param){
        System.out.println(param);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(param);  // convert to json
        return json.toMap();
    }
```

**2. Use Map as request body**

```
    @PostMapping(value="/register")
    public Map<String, Object> registerSingleConnection(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> param){
        System.out.println(param);
        return param;
    }
```

**3. Use a custom type as request body**

```
    public class Request {
        private String id;
        private String val;

        public Request(String id, String val) {
            this.id = id;
            this.val = val;
        }

        public JSONObject toJSON() {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("id", id);
            json.put("val", val);

            return json;
        }
    }


    @PostMapping(value="/register")
    public Map<String, Object> registerSingleConnection(@RequestBody Request param){
        JSONObject json = param.toJSON();
        return json.toMap();
    }
```

[image]